# Bugs jquery addrow in tag input type file

Tags: jquery, file, row, addition

i have this script

```
<script src="/js/jquery.table.addrow.js">

<table border="0"> 
<tr> 
 <td><input type="file" name="image[]" value=""/></td>  
 <td><a class="delRow" href="javascript:void(0)">delete</a></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
 <td colspan="2">
 <a class="addRow" href="javascript:void(0)" id="1">add</a>  
 </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 

$(document).ready(function(){    
$(".addRow").btnAddRow();   
$(".delRow").btnDelRow(); });
```

This works, but if I use firefox to make additions row and the first file input tag type is selected a file, the file input tag carried by the new file type.
when I want a new input tag is empty.

This does not happen if I use crome.

how do i solve this problem ..
is there anything that can help :)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kfqTP/)

Comment: Where does `btnAddRow` come from?

Comment: from jquery addrow plugin. 
this my reference http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/table.addrow.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its the correct way, but you could use a callback function, that gets called after new row is added, and set the value of the input to blank, like:

```
$(".addRow").btnAddRow(function(obj){
    $(obj).find("input[type='file']").val(''); //get input and sent it empty
});   
$(".delRow").btnDelRow();
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfqTP/9/)

Comment: GREAT
this works well.

Thank you very much sudhir .. :D
you are very helpful